# Angular Material $mdDialog is covered by the Kendo popup window

Tags: html, angularjs, kendo-ui, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material in my AngularJS project and want to replace the alert windows (opened by alert() function) with the [Angular Material dialog](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog) so that the style will be consistent.

I've gone through the demos and documents provided by Angular Material and bound the function to ng-click.

```
<md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="showAlert($event)"   >
  Save
</md-button>
```

The button is inside a popup Kendo window, opened by kWindow.open() function.

```
var windowInstance = $kWindow.open({
                /// Logic omitted
            });
```

In my current logic, when the button is clicked, a service will be called to post data to the server. After that I want to show the alert with the message "Saved successfully". The problem is that, the Angular Material dialog will be covered by the popup window.

How can I fix this issue so that the dialog will display on the top as the alert window does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I investigated and found that I can set the z-index property of the Angular Material dialog in the CSS file to change the layer height. In my case, 10000 is still covered by the window, while 20000 works correctly.

```
.md-dialog-container {
    z-index: 20000;
}
```